# Map operation over a KStream fails when not specifying default serdes and using custom ones -> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Since I am working with Json values I haven't set up default serdes.

I process a KStream, consuming it with the necessary spring and product (json) serdes, but the next step (map operation) fails:

```
val props = Properties()
props[StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG] = applicationName
props[StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = kafkaBootstrapServers

val productSerde: Serde<Product> = Serdes.serdeFrom(JsonPojoSerializer<Product>(), JsonPojoDeserializer(Product::class.java))

builder.stream(INVENTORY_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), productSerde))
            .map { key, value ->
                KeyValue(key, XXX)
            }
            .aggregate(...)
```

If I remove the map operation the execution goes ok.

I haven't found a way to specify the serdes for the map(), how can it be done?

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: com.codependent.kafkastreams.inventory.dto.Product). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:92)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues:

1. After you call `map()` you call `groupByKey().aggregate()`. This triggers data repartition and thus after `map()` data is written into an internal topic for data repartitioning. Therefore, you need to provide corresponding `Serde`s within `groupByKey()`, too.
2. However, because you don't modify the key, you should actually call `mapValues()` instead, to avoid the unnecessary repartitioning.
3. Note, that you need to provide `Serde`s for each operator that should not use the default `Serde` from the config. `Serde`s are not passed along downstream, but are operator in-place overwrites. (It's work in progress for Kafka 2.1 to improve this.)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands here like I did, here's a practical example that demonstrates Matthias' solution. The following code will fail due to a ClassCastException.

```
builder.stream(
        "my-topic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), customSerde))
        .map((k, v) -> {
            // You've modified the key. Get ready for an error!
            String newKey = k.split(":")[0];
            return KeyValue.pair(newKey.toString(), v);
        })
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
            MyAggregate::new,
            (key, data, aggregation) -> {
                // You'll never reach this block due to an error similar to:
                // ClassCastException while producing data to topic
                return aggregation.updateFrom(shot);
            },
            Materialized.<String, MyAggregate> as(storeSupplier)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(aggregateSerde)
        )
```

As Matthias has mentioned, "you need to provide corresponding Serdes within groupByKey". Here's how:

```
builder.stream(
        "my-topic",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), customSerde))
        .map((k, v) -> {
            // You've modified the key. Get ready for an error!
            String newKey = k.split(":")[0];
            return KeyValue.pair(newKey.toString(), v);
        })
        // Voila, you've specified the serdes required by the new internal
        // repartition topic and you can carry on with your work
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), customSerde))
        .aggregate(
            MyAggregate::new,
            (key, data, aggregation) -> {
                // You'll never reach this block due to an error similar to:
                // ClassCastException while producing data to topic
                return aggregation.updateFrom(shot);
            },
            Materialized.<String, MyAggregate> as(storeSupplier)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(aggregateSerde)
        )
```