# Specifying serdes on a map operation in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I'm sorry if this by any chance is a duplicate post, but I have been searching for an answer  and got nothing so far.

What I need is to specify the serdes during a map operation that changes the key type in Kafka Streams.
The original KStream has a string-typed key and avro (GenericRecord) value, but I need to remap it to an avro key and value. Something along these lines:

```
KStream<String, GenericRecord> inputStream = builder.stream("someTopic");
KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> rekeyedStream = inputStream.map((key, value) -> {
   GenericRecord newKey = new GenericData.Record(someSchema);
   ...
   return new KeyValue(newKey, newValue);
});
```

I believe I need to specify the serde since the types are being changed, but I found no way to do it on a map operator. When reading from a topic, grouping or writing back to a topic, we can usually do something like the following to overwrite the default serdes:

```
KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> stream = builder.stream("someTopic", 
    Consumed.with(keySerde, valueSerde));

KGroupedStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> groupedStream = 
    inputStream.groupBy((key, value)->somethingThatChangesTheKey(), 
    Grouped.with(newKeySerde, newValueSerde));

inputStream.to("someTopic", Produced.with(keySerde,valueSerde));
```

And yet I'm at a complete loss as to *how* to specify the serdes in a map when the types change, and in this particular case I can't be using my app's default serdes.

The closest I got to finding a solution was this post right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026148/map-operation-over-a-kstream-fails-when-not-specifying-default-serdes-and-using), but I'm afraid the accepted response told the OP he needs to specify the serdes, but not *how* this may be done during a map (at least as far as I understood, I could be mistaken).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a new serde on `map()` because `map()` does not need the serde. The `map()` operator itself gets an input object and produces an output object, but it never serializes or deserializes any messages.

Only operators that read from or write into a Kafka topic allow you to set a serde, as only those operator would use a serde.

It's not clear to me, what you try to accomplish by setting a serde on the `map()` operator. Can you elaborate?